# Angular checkbox hard-coded to [checked]="true" isn't always true

Tags: angular

I'm troubleshooting a bigger issue, but I've boiled it down to this...

If I have a checkbox `<input type="checkbox">` in Angular, and I hard-code the `[checked]` property to `true`, shouldn't it always show as checked?

Here's an example. If you click the checkbox, it toggles to unchecked, even though the `[checked]` property is always `true`.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange()" [checked]="isChecked()"> Click me and I\'ll uncheck (but I shouldn\'t)',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  isChecked() {
    console.log('isChecked() was called');
    return true;
  }

  onChange() {
    console.log("changed.")
  }     
}
```

The same code on Stackbiltz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example-w8ujt7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks,
-Doug

Comment: Whether always checkbox should be checked and it should not be changed to unchecked??

Comment: Does this is what you want?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example-o2qi4f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an $event in onChange function `<input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)" [checked]="isChecked()"> Click me and I\'ll uncheck (but I shouldn\'t)` so that you can change the value of input.

```
onChange(e) {
  console.log("changed.")
  //here u are again setting the input value as true.
  e.target.checked = true;
}
```

Another way of doing, add **(click)** event in your template like this 
`(click)="onClick($event)"`

and Define a **onClick(e)** function in your component,

```
onClick(e){
   //here u are again setting the input value as true.
   e.target.checked = true;
}
```

But (click) event is better than (change) for this situation.

Comment: That does it, but can you help me understand why it's not sufficient to simply have [checked]="isChecked()" in the HTML?  I see the log entries from isChecked(), so I know it's re-evaluating the value, but the true value that it's returning seems to be getting overwritten or ignored.

Comment: There is a 'checked' property in checkbox. whenever you check/uncheck it becomes true/false. so you need to change it forcefully. and isChecked() function will fire in every change detection. but when u click in checkbox, angular cannot detect change because u r not using [(ngModel)] in ur checkbox. If you do, it cannot do what you want. so, u have to change the value of 'checked' property forcefully.